# Black and White Wires on Switch but No Neutral?

Tags: electrical, wiring, switch, smart-switch

I was going to install a Kasa smart switch, which requires a neutral.  When I opened up this box, which contains 2 switches that control 2 separate lights outside (porch and walkway), I noticed black and white wires going into both switches.  Is this a sign of a switch loop for both outside lights?  Does this mean that the white wire is not neutral but hot?  Thanks for any help you can give a newbie!

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's exactly what it means, no neutral at the location. There are smart switches that don't require neutrals so you might want to check them out.

Comment: Thanks, Jack.  Was hoping to avoid the dimmer and hub versions of smart switches, but looks like that's cheaper than adding neutrals...